# Tensorflow, expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I'm using `tf.keras` and I'm getting following error:

> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (24946, 50, 50)

Could someone help me with it?

Code (Image_Size is: `50x50`)

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import pickle
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D


pickle_ind = open("x.pickle", "rb")
x = pickle.load(pickle_ind)
x = np.array(x, dtype=float)
# x = x/255.0

pickle_ind = open("y.pickle", "rb")
y = pickle.load(pickle_ind)

n_batch = len(x)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=20, batch_size=n_batch)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `channels` dimension:

```py
x = np.expand_dims(x, -1)
```

You also need to add output dense layer:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(50, 50, 1)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_softmax_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: hello, i got this (ValueError: A target array with shape (24946, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 9, 9, 64) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.)

Comment: i try to add that you added and i got this: ValueError: A target array with shape (24946, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 2) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Comment: updated again just now. It is better to use it that way

Comment: thanks but got another error now, next step for me (cuda error :s)