# InvalidArgumentError while using Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I was trying to use tensorboard to look at my model. But I get an InvalidArgumentError.

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  # this converts our 3D feature maps to 1D feature vectors

model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

model.fit(x = X_train, 
          y = y_train, 
          epochs = 10, 
          validation_split = 0.1, 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

When I remove the `callbacks=[tensorboard_callback]` the model trains fine but when I include it, it spits out the following error.

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'conv2d_input' with dtype float and shape [?,50,50,1]
     [[{{node conv2d_input}}]]
```

Comment: I have defined tensorboard callback object by the way. ```tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)```

Comment: Does this related post answer your question too? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/56008114/2815

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't!