# InvalidArgumentError while using TensorBoard on a TensorFlow Hub Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, tensorboard, bert-language-model

So I was using [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert) to learn about the BERT model and about importing models from Tensorflow Hub.

Original Code([Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/text/classify_text_with_bert.ipynb)):

```
print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_ds,
                               validation_data=val_ds,
                               epochs=epochs)
```

Now I tried to add TensorBoard to the Model.fit() function, but got this error after 12 frames.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of bool is not in the list of allowed values: float, double, int32, uint8, int16, int8, int64, bfloat16, uint16, half, uint32, uint64
    ; NodeDef: {{node WriteHistogramSummary}}; Op<name=WriteHistogramSummary; signature=writer:resource, step:int64, tag:string, values:T -> ; attr=T:type,default=DT_FLOAT,allowed=[DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, DT_INT8, DT_INT64, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_UINT16, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64]; is_stateful=true> [Op:WriteHistogramSummary]
```

My Code([Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Zd0n6oXYb4Jan1t9gpjIV88CENFHXMdI?usp=sharing)):

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

```
!rm -rf ./logs/
```

```
log_dir = "logs/fit/" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1)
```

```
print(f'Training model with {tfhub_handle_encoder}')
history = classifier_model.fit(x=train_ds,
                               validation_data=val_ds,
                               epochs=epochs,
                               callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

```
%tensorboard --logdir logs/fit
```

A similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61840829/invalidargumenterror-while-using-tensorboard) but it got no replies.

Please help!

Edit 1: Error's Screenshot
[image: Error Screenshot]

Please suggest any edits.

Answer (score 1):

there is an open issue on the TensorFlow repo on GitHub.
[issue #43200](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43200)

A fix is being proposed but I don't know if it is implemented in the core framework yet (hence the issue being open).